# Self-defined Function while creating a Digital twin?

Tags: eclipse-ditto, eclipse-digital-twin

It is possible to add a self-defined function while creating a digital Twin in Ditto as shown below.

```
"attributes": {
    "location": "Germany"
},
"features": {
    "temperature": {
        "properties": {
            "value": 100
        }
    },
    "humidity": {
        "properties": {
            "value": 100
        }
    }
},
"BuiltinFuntion": {
    if(Temparature > 20){
   alert("Some message")
}
}
```

Note: One solution is to constantly check with Ditto HTTP APIs value and give alert message whenever it cross the threshold value. But I do not want to hit the APIs everytime. So please let me know if there is any alternate solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order not to poll Ditto's API for changes, there are various other APIs supporting push-notifications.

For example, you can use the [WebSocket API](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/httpapi-protocol-bindings-websocket.html) and use an [filter expression](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-changenotifications.html#by-rql-expression) defining `filter=gt(features/temperature/properties/value,20)` when [subscribing for events](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/httpapi-protocol-bindings-websocket.html#request-events).
Or you can use the [SSE (Server Sent Events) API](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/httpapi-sse.html#filtering-by-rql-expression) to do the same.

Both, the WebSocket and SSE API may directly be used in the browser - I suppose your `alert` you want to show is JavaScript, so I assumed your target environment for receiving push notifications is a browser.